# How to override an association (has_one) getter (lazy loading)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It seems like there are a lot of questions (and answers) to this topic for Rails 3, but I'm asking now in 2015 for Rails 4 (or upcoming 5).

I tried using a pattern like the following (for a has_one association in the case of a User::Profile that I'd like to lazy load):

```
def profile
    self.build_profile unless self[:profile]
    super
end
```

The issue is that the above ends up with a Profile object without an .id, so the table just gets appended with unassociated records.

This works (but I'm calling super twice, and I don't know enough about ruby to know if this is a terrible thing -- no warnings):

```
def profile
    self.build_profile unless super
    super
end
```

The active record docs indicate that you can use super or *_attribute (or []), but there seems to be something different for associations in how 'super' is implemented.

I can still use alias method chaining, but I'm wondering what's wrong with my pattern.

Edit: It appears that using "accepts_nested_attributes_for" complicates this matter.

Comment: I removed the overidden getter and changed my 'fields_for' to include the simple logic of creating a place holder object ex: <%= f.fields_for :profile, (user.profile || user.build_profile) do |profile_f| %> This is not an answer to my question, but it is a perfectly acceptable solution to my issue presented.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your first example doesn't have an id is because `build_profile` is because it only instantiates a new `Profile` object without saving it to the database.  If you want it saved to the database then and there, you should use `create_profile` instead.  Also, `super` will return `nil` if a profile doesn't yet exist.  Try this simple approach:

```
def profile
  super || self.create_profile
end
```

For details on the helper methods that come with a `has_one` association, see section 4.2.1 of the Rails' docs:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

Comment: Well I don't know what context you are invoking this method, so I'm not sure what qualifies as a working solution. Correct me if I'm wrong I believe but both approaches you suggested will return a new `Profile` object without an id (just like `Profile.new`) unless there already exists an associated profile in the database.

Comment: The 2nd method shown, ends up with a valid record being saved to the store (with id). There is no other difference in the implementation.

Comment: Neither method you suggested actually writes to the database.  You must be calling `.save` or similar at some point after the method is called. No?

Comment: Right... but I meant in the implementation (which includes the controller's boilerplate update) there's no other change. The 2nd method works. So there must be something in the attribute getter's super that is affecting the update?